# TFIDVectorizer for Word Embedding/Vectorization

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I want to compare two bodies of text ( A and B ) and check for the similarity between them

Here's my current approach:

```
Turn both bodies of text into vectors

Compare these vectors using a cosine similarity measure

Return the result
```

The very first step is what is giving me pause. How would I do this with TFIDVectorizer? Is it enough to put both bodies of text in a list, fit_transform them and then put their resultant matrices in my cosine similarity measure?

Is there some training process with TFIDVectorizer, a vocabulary matrix ( fit() )? If so, how do I turn A and B into vectors so that I could put them into a cosine similarity measure?

P.S I understand what other options exist, I'm curious specifically about TFIDVectorizer

Comment: At the very least you must fit the TFIDVectorizer with the full text made of A and B, or if possible some broader corpus containing the two texts. But even like this the IDF part is not going to work very well, because the doc frequency can only be 1 or 2.

Comment: @Erwan Would it make sense to load, say 50, documents from a directory and convert each one to an element in a list. The fit the vectorizer with that list?

Comment: Certainly, assuming these 50 documents belong to the same corpus, or at least are somehow related to the input documents. This would initialize the IDF weights more accurately.

Comment: Perfect! Just to clarify: I'd 'fit' using those documents. And then I'd turn A and B into vectors using 'transform'. Then that goes into a cosine similarity function?

Comment: Yes, fitting on the whole corpus and then transform any input document, for instance A and B. This gives you two vectors on which you can compute a cosine for instance. TFIDF would help a bit by giving more weight to rare words, but it's not a perfect measure of course. Also it works better if the documents are large.